# What do I really need to register as a resident in Italy?

Tags: citizenship, residency, italy, europe

I am looking to go to Italy with my non-EU passport and register as resident (that means doing the inscrizione anagrafica).

My passport allows me to stay there for up to three months. Since I am going to have my Jus Sanguinis Citizenship recognised, there is an Italian law that states I do not need a visa for that registration.

However, I cannot find any list of documents that actually make sense. Some of them just list passport and visa. What will I present as a proof of residence?

E.g suppose I stay at someone's house. How would that work?